# how can I start cowboy websocket from other client

Tags: erlang, websocket, cowboy

I started the cowboy example websocket server in my machine, and tested ok with localhost
but in other client it doesn't work
how can it work?

Comment: What do you mean saying in other client?

Comment: not localhost,I test with localhost:8080 is ok,but I test from another machine with 192.168.17.100:8080(it is my ip) will not work

Comment: In what way doesn't it work? You'll need to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure your firewall allows port 8080 on an inbound connection.